# Adding Textbox to a Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I am using a GridView to get data from a datasource.
I want to add a textbox at the end of each column in the GridView i.e at the footer
How do I do that?

Comment: `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `FooterTemplate`. Example:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        your textboxes go here
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        your textboxes go here
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: When I put  
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" ReadOnly="True"  SortExpression="Number" FooterText="Number"/>

in ItemTemplate. .it gives me warning/error .
What to do?

Comment: You can't use the BoundField and TemplateField in the same column. You'll have use the template field and do something like <%# Eval("DataField") %> in the ItemTemplate to output the data to that column.

Comment: As @Ricketts said you can't use BoundField and TemplateField. Instead of  `<ItemTemplate><asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Number" FooterText="Number"/></ItemTemplate>` try `<ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Number") %></ItemTemplate>`

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the differences between the BoundField and the TemplateField class. The first is used to display fields as a text, while in the TemplateField you can customize the way you're going to display the information. So, you should use BoundField **or** TemplateField in a column (not one nested inside another as I think you're trying), in your case it has to be the TemplateField, because you want to customize the way your footer shows up. So, it should be something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Number")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add TextBox in `<FooterTemplate>`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UnitsInStock">
         <ItemTemplate>
            //your displaying control
         </ItemTemplate>                  
         <FooterTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox id="tb1" Text="Text" runat="server" />
         </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

Find footer control in OnRowDataBound event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
   {
       TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("tb1");
       //do your stuff 
   } 
}
```